# Backbone Router : Get rid of # in the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm getting backbone router to work

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "todo": "todo"
      },
      todo: function() {
        alert(1);
      }
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

This works well when I goto url : **domain:port/#/todo**

I want this to work without # in the URL, I tried putting pushState parameter as mentioned in the documents.

```
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

This simply redirects # url to the non hashed one

**domain:port/#/todo (redirects to ==>)  domain:port/todo**

But when I visit this URL directly

**domain:port/todo**

it doesn't work: "Cannot GET /todo".

Is there any way, I can make this URL work without # in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write server side code to deliver the page for the URL.

Using `pushState` just tells the browser "I have used JS to change the content of the page so it matches what you would get if you ask for this URL".

It doesn't cause the content to match that URL, you have to do that as a separate task.

Comment: Quentin is absolutely right.  Here is a series of tutorials for using PushState.  Word of warning, though.  If you're just playing around with the ToDo app, then I'm assuming you're a Backbone newbie.  This is pretty advanced stuff.  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/, http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/, http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/06/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-3-the-video/.

Comment: @sublime — No, you get the alert when "you use JS to change to the content of the page", you haven't written the server side code that delivers the same result if the URL is accessed directly.

Comment: It is going to be a single page app, so I'm really confused as to what content a server should deliver?

Comment: It should deliver the app in the state that it would be in if you loaded it in the default state and then performed the actions that cause you to change the URL to the one requested from the server.

Comment: Here is what I did, I changed ::  app.get('/', send html file ); TO THIS ::  app.get('\*',send html file);      but now while sending this html file i get an error saying: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  (at the start of html file)
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});