# Getting backbone routing to work with pushstate and node.js/express as server

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, express, url-routing

I'm trying to build a single page app with backbone.js on front end and node.js/express as server, I want to have a base HTML file for the root, and then when user navigates to any path such as

```
mydomain.com/foo/bar
```

I want to be able to handle that path on the client side by javascript instead of making a round trip to server. I am reading about backbone routing and HTML5 push state.  In [this article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/) he describes push state like this,

*In fact, PushState is really nothing more than a standard API for JavaScript, that allows us to manipulate the browser history by “push”ing full URLs into the browser’s URL without making a round trip to the server, and respond to changes in the URL with Javascript – all without the use of URL hash fragments.*

but when I use push state it does actually makes a server request and expects server to deliver contents under /foo/bar . I don't understand how I can avoid that.

Now let's assume that even with push state, your client is going to make a server request under mydomain.com/foo/bar when you visit this URL directly. In that case, since I'm serving the default HTML file, and this default HTML file has links to scripts in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js" ></script>
```

When this HTML loads, it starts looking for scripts under /foo directory instead of root since the server was requested under /foo which obviously does not exist. How do I fix this?

I'm really confused at this point. I'd like to know how URL routing is usually done in a single page application. Any help will be greatly appreciated. You can also refer to this other question I have posted about the same issue: [Backbone Router : Get rid of # in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571288/backbone-router-get-rid-of-in-the-url/22571461)

Comment: I just had the same issue the other day. Except I used node.js and express on the backend to serve the routes. I think in my experience push state may require some serverside response, take that with a grain of salt. On the server I allow express to render a file for example on this route `localhost:3300/chat` and on the client side I allow push state and render a view when this route is hit `localhost:3300/chat`.

Comment: Another thing that helped was writing backbone.history like this `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/'});` Try adding a root `/` Does your app/site start on the main route `/`

Comment: Then make sure your router is set up correctly `appRoutes: {
        ''     : 'profile',
        'chat' : 'chat'
    }`

Comment: default root is set to '/' so that's not the problem.

Comment: Yes I'm using express.js on my backend, but since It's a single page app I don't really have different contents for different urls. It's only one HTML file. But the problem is when I deliver it from some different route then all the scripts linked inside that HTML get messed up as well.

Answer (score 4):

The solution you're trying to implement is very interesting but not that simple. When your server gets a request to `mydomain.com/foo/bar`, you should redirect to your root with some parameter that the frontend (JavaScript) app can pick-up to know what the original request was for. For example:

1. Client sends GET `http://mydomain.com/foo/bar`
2. Server redirects (responds 302 with Location header set) to `http://mydomain.com/#!/foo/bar`
3. Your SPA is loaded in the browser, and on startup you check for the hash and find `#!/foo/bar`, so you remove the hash and trigger the `/foo/bar` route (that's a push-state). Your resulting URL is again `http://mydomain.com/foo/bar`: the original URL the user browsed to.

[Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/) does something similar to this, though it actually responds with a page to the request sent in 1., which does the hash replacement in the client and then sends another request to the server. It looks unnecessary to me, maybe I'm overlooking something.